# java.security.InvalidKeyException: unknown version: 3 - bounty castle

Tags: java, openssl, rsa, bouncycastle, azure-keyvault

I am getting the error as "java.security.InvalidKeyException: unknown version: 3" on generatePrivate method below in the code snippet. I am unable to find the root cause why it is causing this error. I retrieved the private key of the parent certificate using the azure SecretClient and then creating the PrivateKey object to pass it for signing the child certificate. Really not sure why generatePrivate method below is throwing an exception when the keySpec is passed that is retrieved from keyvault for parent cert. Not sure what am doing wrong here?

```
            var privateKeyBase64 = azureKeyVaultClient.getSecretClient().getSecret(certificateName).getValue();
            byte[] privateKeyBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(privateKeyBase64);
            var keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privateKeyBytes);
            var privateKeyParent = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePrivate(keySpec);
```

Comment: An AKV 'secret', unlike a key' (or 'certificate'), can store any string (of moderate size); it doesn't have to be a privatekey, and if it is a privatekey it doesn't have to be PKCS8-clear format. Your keyvault contains something that is NOT a PKCS8-clear privatekey, although it does appear to use ASN.1 and begin with an integer; this eliminates some of the many zillion possibilities. You need to either find out what it is, and code for that if possible, or change it to be a (base64-encoded) PKCS8-clear privatekey.

Comment: thank you for your reply and I figured that it is a formatting issue of the private key as the one am retrieving back is not in PKCS8 format and planning to adjust that and test it soon.

Comment: @Sam It's great to hear that you were able to resolve your issue. Could you please document your solution in an answer? It would provide clarity for those encountering similar technical challenges within the community.